# Count the number of occurrences of a string with a variable substring in a file in bash

Tags: string, bash, grep

I want to count the number of occurrences of a string `Exiting with return code $var` in a text file `dump.out` where `0<$var<29`.

i.e. I only want to consider the strings where `$var` is any value between `0` and `29` including both the limits.

I want to check it like this:

```
if [ $(grep -c "Exiting with return code 0" dump.out) -ne 5 ]; then
  rc=1
  exit 0
fi
```

But here only string with `0`s are considered.

Any suggestions will be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
grep -c -E 'Exiting with return code [12]?[0-9]([^0-9]|$)' dump.out
```

`-E` let grep use the extended regex (ERE)
`[12]?[0-9]` is matching numbers 0,1,...,29
`([^0-9]|$)` matches the end of the line or anything except a digit

Answer (score 0):

For 0 <= $var <= 29

```
grep -c 'Exiting with return code \([0-9]\|[12][0-9]\)'
```

For 0 < $var < 29

```
grep -c 'Exiting with return code \([1-9]\|1[0-9]\|2[0-8]\)'
```

Note that it can match 134, as it start with `1`, so you might need to specify the following character (or `$` if there's none).

Answer (score 0):

**Try this may be this will help**

```
grep -w -c "Exiting with return code [012][0-9]\|Exiting with return code [0-9]" dump.out
```